# Is it possible to use EE, Structure and Playa to create multiple related listings and detail pages?

Tags: expressionengine

We have a single channel that holds all the information for one dataset, in our case, Producers.

We have multiple Event type channels, for each of the Events that our client holds every year.

We then add an entry which holds a relationship field to the Producer channel, so that we can show a list of Producers attending that particular Event.

This works fine, but can be labour intensive if for example 200 Producers attend an Event, as we would have to create 200 new entries in that particular Event type channel.

We thought Playa might make this a better admin process, as it allows you to multiple select relationships within one Playa field. Therefore, each Event type channel would have just one entry, that had a Playa field holding all the Producer relationships.

Trouble is, we can't get this to work with Structure, as Structure does not seem to recognise the individual relationships. The following code lists the Producers for an Event, but does not link through to the detail page as the {page_uri} variable for each listing is empty (this is why we presume the relationship is not recognised):

```
{exp:structure:entries}

    {exp:playa:children field="producers" limit="5"}
        <p><a href="{page_uri}">{page_uri}</a></p>

    {/exp:playa:children}

{/exp:structure:entries}
```

Can Expression Engine, Structure and Playa work in this way, and if so, how do we correct the above template code?

Comment: Hey- This question is pretty specific to EE, you might have better luck posting it over at expressionengine.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Thanks, just done it http://goo.gl/16gah